# Asp.net MVC Bundle - Only application relative URLs (~/url) are allowed

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I am getting below error while including script in bundle . Is  there a way to solve this

> The URL '/Scripts/bootstrap.js?1.0.0.1' is not valid. Only
>   application relative URLs (~/url) are allowed.

We are using CDN so url's will be created like 'bootstrap.js?1.0.0.1' .I found few articles but nothing solved the problem.

Comment: You wouldn't be bundling a remote resource then; you'd have the resource on the CDN already bundled/minified (and therefore included as a traditional `<script>` reference).

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, add the `~` to the start of your path, . The `~` is synonymous to the application root.

Comment: To supplement James' answer, the bundler needs "hard" access to the file, not remote access to a resource. So requiring `~/` just ensures it's a local resource it has access to without a round-trip.

Answer (score 5):

You can use MVC Bundles with a CDN. Obviously, as with any CDN, you should have some sort of plan for a fallback (usually a local copy) in case the CDN is not available. (I say that having never actually bothered, but just because I'm lazy doesn't mean you should be!)

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{

    bundles.UseCdn = true;   //enable CDN support

    //add link to bootstrap on the CDN
    var bootstrapCdnPath = "http://domain.to/bootstrap.cdn";

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap",
                bootstrapCdnPath));

}
```

Note that this always uses the CDN, even in debug mode. See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification (when it's up, or use Google cache) for more about how you can use a local copy (e.g., non-minified) when debugging.

Comment: "_usually a local copy_" -- With .NET MVC, what's your other option?

Answer (score 3):

The error you are receiving is that your URL isn't relative. The URL '/Scripts/bootstrap.js?1.0.0.1' refers to the actualy url `http:////Scripts/bootstrap.js?1.0.0.1` - **This is a static URL**

Obviously this is not what you are tryin to achieve. You are attempting to achieve the reference of `http://yourdomain.com/Scripts/bootstrap.js?1.0.0.1`.

To achieve this you need to make sure to make it relative to your domain (hence a relative path) by writing the character `~` infront of the resource you wish to reference, as this represents your domain.

Therefor write:

`~/Scripts/bootstrap.js?1.0.0.1`