# Asp.net Error while trying to create a bundle - Only application relative URLs (~/url) are allowed

Tags: c#, asp.net, bundles

I am getting an error, when trying to include a css file in the bundle, it says that `Asp.net MVC Bundle - Only application relative URLs (~/url) are allowed`.

Here is the code:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/bundles/lib/anim_css").Include(
                "~Vendor/lib/animate/animate.min.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

Where the `Vendor` folder is the source folder of that css. That folder is included in the project, being like that ...ProjectFolderName/Vendor

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831176/asp-net-mvc-bundle-only-application-relative-urls-url-are-allowed/23832027) did not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`~Vendor/lib/animate/animate.min.css` is not a legal relative URL. It needs to be `~/Vendor/lib/animate/animate.min.css`